# Looping through nested array vaues in JSON, appending those values to generated html

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

EDITED:

I'm (still) having a little trouble getting values from a nested array in JSON and appending them to generated html.

I'm currently using the following JSON (updated):

```
{
    "OuterArray": [
        {
            "memberId": "01",
            "key01": "",
            "included": "true",
            "nestedArray": [
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" },
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "memberId": "02",
            "key01": "",
            "included": "true",
            "nestedArray": [
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" },
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "memberId": "03",
            "key01": "",
            "included": "false",
            "nestedArray": [
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" },
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "memberId": "04",
            "key01": "",
            "included": "true",
            "nestedArray": [
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" },
                { "keyA": "", "keyB": "" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this js:

```
for (var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
    if (outerArray[i].included !== "false") {

    var key01 = outerArray[i].key01;
    var key02 = outerArray[i].key02;
    // etc.

    var nestedArray = outerArray[i]["nestedArray"];

    myDiv.innerHTML +=
        "<div class=\"outer-array-stuff\">"
            + "<p class=\"key01\">" + key01 + "</p>"
            + "<p class=\"key02\">" + key02 + "</p>"

            + "<div class=\"nested-array-stuff\">" // help?
            + "</div>"
        + "</div>"

    var nestedArrayStuff = document.getElementsByClassName("nested-array-stuff")[i];

    for (var j=0; j<outerArray.length; j++) {
        nestedArrayStuff.innerHTML += "<p class=\"keyA\">" + nestedArray[j].keyA + "</p>";
    }
}
```

Note that one of the keys in the outer array has a boolean value which determines whether or not it (the outer array member) is - and its nested array stuff are - included in the page.

So just to reiterate, the goal is:

```
<div class="outer-array-stuff">
    <!-- <snip: some outer array key/values here /> -->
    <div class="nested-array-stuff">
    <div class="nested-array-stuff">
        <p>[e.g., nested array key 1 value]</p>
        <p>[e.g., nested array key 2 value]</p>
        <p>[etc.]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If all the outer array members 'included' are 'true', everything outer & nested loads, but this is not exactly what I want; I need to filter so that only those 'included' !== "false". So now my problem is that despite being inside the if 'included'/else loop, the outer array members stop loading at the first *excluded* outer array member (actually, the next 'true' outer array member does load, but its nested array stuff doesn't, and then nothing further loads, the entire outer array loop dies.

Any insight as to why this is happening?

Many thanks to dreyescat for the help to this point.

P.S. generally I'm trying to minimize my reliance on jQuery.

Many thanks, svs

Comment: Same way you did for outer array?

Comment: @skobaljic Not sure I understand what you're getting at; the nested array loop is within the outer array loop as well as within the if 'included'/else loop; so why does the entire outer loop die once it hits an non-included outer array member, even though if I remove the nested loop code altogether, the if/else includes all the expected outer array members, no problem skipping the non-included, and completes to the end of the json. Cheers, svs

Comment: Btw, fwiw, 'nestedArrayStuff is undefined' error occurs when the loop dies, so it seems like the nested loop is somehow not getting the memo to ignore non-included outer array members; it's trying to load nested array stuff into non-existent 'nestedArrayStuff' elements maybe? I dunno, I'm confused, sad, lonely, cold, hungry ;)

Comment: You go with `if typeof nestedArrayStuff!='undefined'`

Comment: oops I see `myDiv.innerHTML += ...`, should you set `mydiv` for each outer item?

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks. I tried adding this condition both inside & outside the nested array loop; either way the outer loop continues thru the outer array, but still the nested array members are ignored after the first non-included outer array member. So there IS a 'myDiv' generated, each containing a div.nested-array-stuff, but only the first couple of .nested-array-stuff are loading. I'm baffled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Here is your code revised with some comments.

```
// Generally is not a good practice iterate arrays using for..in
//for (var i in outerArray) {
for (var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
    var key01 = outerArray[i].key01;
    var key02 = outerArray[i].key02;
    // This should by outerArray array and not jsonData object.
    var nestedArray = outerArray[i]["nestedArray"];

    myDiv.innerHTML +=
        "<div class=\"outer-array-stuff\">"
            + "<p class=\"key01\">" + key01 + "</p>"
            + "<p class=\"key02\">" + key02 + "</p>"

            + "<div class=\"nested-array-stuff\">" // help?
            + "</div>"
        + "</div>"

    // getElementsByClassName gets a list of elements that have that class.
    // I suppose you want to add the elements to the corresponding outer array.
    // Let's use the loop index i to get the proper parent element. You could also
    // just get the last one.
    var nestedArrayStuff = document.getElementsByClassName("nested-array-stuff")[i]; // help?
    // Again I recommend you not to use for..in for arrays.
    for (var obj in nestedArray) {
        nestedArrayStuff.innerHTML += "<p class=\"keyA\">" + nestedArray[obj].keyA + "</p>"; // NOPE
    }
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdjt52ab/).

You could also build the entire nested array stuff before adding it to the div element. Then you don't need to query the document to get the nested array stuff element.

```
for (var i in outerArray) {
    var key01 = outerArray[i].key01;
    var key02 = outerArray[i].key02;
    var nestedArray = outerArray[i]["nestedArray"];

    var nestedArrayStuff = '<div class=\"nested-array-stuff\">';    
    for (var obj in nestedArray) {
        nestedArrayStuff += "<p class=\"keyA\">" + nestedArray[obj].keyA + "</p>"; // NOPE
    } 
    nestedArrayStuff += '</div>';
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<div class=\"outer-array-stuff\">"
            + "<p class=\"key01\">" + key01 + "</p>"
            + "<p class=\"key02\">" + key02 + "</p>"
            + nestedArrayStuff
            + "</div>"
        + "</div>";
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k7s47ggd/)

Comment: Many thanks! Btw, I apologize for my tardy response but for that I can blame my 2011 MBP which tends to shut down randomly and stay down for hours of restarts. 

Anyway, your help is greatly appreciated. However I now have a new problem, er, opportunity to learn! I've updated my post to more accurately reflect my JSON and to detail the new issue. I would be grateful for any further insight. Cheers!

Comment: I have been hacking at this problem for days; yet another experience where I anticipated a relatively concise correction to what I built. Anyway, after a depressing # of hours and days of confusion, I solved my problem with your 2nd version. Thanks again, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`nestedArray` is not a string. your `nestedArray` array loop should be as follows.

```
var nestedArray = outerArray[i].nestedArray;   
for (var j in nestedArray) {
 console.log(nestedArray[j].keyA);
 console.log(nestedArray[j].keyB);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me confirm my nested array var.

Comment: Please do not use `for... in` loops to iterate arrays.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum wait, what? this is wrong? for (var i in outerArray) { for (var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) { ... ???

Answer (score 0):

Here is [your complete solution](http://jsfiddle.net/j96678rg/), I used lists to output content. It assumes we have one container:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Than JS would be:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var outerArray = [
    {
        "memberId":"01",
        "key01":"",
        "key02":"key02 exists, ...",
        "included":"true",
        "nestedArray":[
            {
                "keyA":"1",
                "keyB":"2"
            },
            {
                "keyA":"3",
                "keyB":"4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "memberId":"02",
        "key01":"key01 value..",
        "included":"true",
        "nestedArray":[
            {
                "keyA":"5",
                "keyB":""
            },
            {
                "keyA":"",
                "keyB":"8"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "memberId":"03",
        "key02":"",
        "included":"false",
        "nestedArray":[
            {
                "keyA":"",
                "keyB":"9"
            },
            {
                "keyA":"",
                "keyB":""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "memberId":"04",
        "key01":"value of key01",
        "key02":"key02 value ...",
        "included":"true",
        "nestedArray":[
            {
                "keyA":"",
                "keyB":"10"
            },
            {
                "keyA":"11",
                "keyB":"12"
            }
        ]
    }
];


var insertHtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {
    if (outerArray[i].included !== "false") {
        insertHtml += "<ul class=\"outer-array-stuff\">";
        insertHtml += "    <li>";
        insertHtml += "     <p class=\"memberId\">memberId(" + i + "): " + outerArray[i].memberId + "</p>"
        insertHtml += "     <p class=\"key01\">key01: " + ( ( typeof outerArray[i].key01!='undefined' && outerArray[i].key01 ) ? outerArray[i].key01 : '') + "</p>"
        insertHtml += "     <p class=\"key02\">key02: " + ( ( typeof outerArray[i].key02!='undefined' && outerArray[i].key02 ) ? outerArray[i].key02 : '') + "</p>"
        var nestedArray = outerArray[i]["nestedArray"];
        if ( nestedArray.length>0 ) {
            insertHtml += "     <ul class=\"nested-array-stuff\">"
            for (var j=0; j<nestedArray.length; j++) {
                insertHtml += "<li class=\"keyA\">keyA(" + j + "): " + nestedArray[j].keyA + "</li>";
                insertHtml += "<li class=\"keyB\">keyB(" + j + "): " + nestedArray[j].keyB + "</li>";
            };
            insertHtml += "     </ul>"
        };
        insertHtml += "    </li>";
        insertHtml += "</ul>"
    }
}
myDiv.innerHTML = insertHtml;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was working on something similar, I thought I would end up with a loop within the generated html. I'll be working on it. Cheers!

Comment: @skobalic I am very thankful for your time on this. Though it was obviously working on jsfiddle, I had some trouble adapting it to my actual content. Ultimately I was able to adapt dreyescat's 2nd suggestion which anyway is similar to yours. Cheers!